# Group manager permission dosen't work in other world

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I have spend a lot of time making a group in group manager and given the group permissions, but when I add myself to the group and go to another world the permissions don't follow - it's like I never made a group. When I go back in the world where I made the groups they come again. How can I get the groups to work in all worlds?

I have tried to set the worlds in the mirror section in the config file but when I do that nothing works - it just let me do anything.

Comment: You could have just added this to the other post :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to do is add this permission: `essentials.world.worldname`

For example: `essentials.world.world_nether`

With this permission, your group's permissions will follow you to the nether. I just found out this after a while testing on my own server, having the same problem. If there is anything else you need help with feel free to add me on skype; `andersberg90`.

I have my own server with a lot of plugins and starting to get pretty experienced with the configuration of plugins :)

Comment: Would it be: essentials.(world name).(world name)_nether?